# Product of 2 random variables:domain of integration

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I am trying to compute the PDF of the product of two ind. random variables: $Z=XY$, where  $0\leq x \leq d$  and  $ 0\leq y \leq 1 $.   ($0<d<1$)

I found this formula : $ f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{|y|} f_{Y}(y) f_X( \frac{z}{y}) dy $.
 How to determine the domain of integration ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $z$ in the interval $(0,d)$, the integration is over the interval $\frac{z}{d}\le y\le 1$ .

The variable $y$ must be positive and $\le 1$, since $f_Y(y)=0$  outside $[0,1]$.

The restriction $y\ge \frac{z}{d}$ comes from the fact that if $y\lt \frac{z}{d}$, then $\frac{z}{y}\gt \frac{z}{z/d}=d$. But then $f_X\left(\frac{z}{y}\right)=0$.

Comment: thank you. I am just looking for the domain of integration; could  you please tell me how you get this interval ?

Comment: I have moved the explanation from a comment to the answer.

Comment: Could I ask you one more question plz (not related to this topic)?

Comment: Sure. But answering questions properly in a comment can be difficult: poor editing facilities, limited space. If it really is a different question, it may be best to ask it separately, and possibly get ideas from several people.

Comment: I had asked this question on mathoverflow, here is the [link](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/173039/laplace-transform-of-t-gamma-1-f-alpha-beta-delta-t-where-f-is-the)

Comment: I need to compute this integral in the interval $[0,d]$ ( or $[d,\infty]$   comment on answer 1 )

Comment: Special functions are not at all my field!

Comment: $0 \leq  z \leq d $ and $0 \leq  y \leq 1 $. are we allowed to divide $z$ by $y$ ($\frac{z}{y}$) without considering the case when $y=0$ and $z=0$ ($\frac{0}{0}$) ?

Comment: In the density case we get $Y=0$ with probability $0$, so it doesn't matter.